# Is there are any potentional problems of creating map inside method and returning view?

Tags: java, collections

Here is simple example.

```
class A {
  public Collection method() {
    Map map = new HashMap();
    // populating map
    return map.values();
  }
}
```

It looks like everything must be ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats fine. Of course it depends on what you want to achieve with this. You will no longer be able to access the map itself unless you kept a reference to it somewhere.